# How do you program a 1x4 Matrix Keypad in Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python

I bought a 1x4 Matrix Keypad https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshopee.com.my%2F-Luminense-1x4-Matrix-Memberane-Switch-Keypad-Numpad-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-i.63040732.4334990197&psig=AOvVaw3QWnV3IR_JBdNoAzRS-wYA&ust=1635615109861000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwjk25Wek_DzAhVCsksFHW_dBtsQr4kDegQIARBc for use in my Raspberry pi 4. The problem I'm facing is I do not know how to program it properly, I did try to make my own code (12 in total) but none of them seem to work properly. Sometimes the code runs but doesn't show the input when I press the button and sometimes it just shows different inputs that's not even the same with the keypad numbering. I need to fix this problem ASAP for my final year project as the due date is near. Anybody know how?

This is the 12th code I made for this keypad

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
button1=16
button2=37
button3=31
button4=29
GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(button2,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(button3,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(button4,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while (1):
  if GPIO.input(button1)==1:
    print("1")
  sleep(0.5)
  if GPIO.input(button2)==1:
    print("2")
  sleep(0.5)
  if GPIO.input(button3)==1:
    print("3")
  sleep(0.5)
  if GPIO.input(button4)==1:
    print("4")
  sleep(0.5)
```

[[image: The input from the program, if i press 1 it gave me 3 as an input.1]

I have other codes for this keypad too but this is the one that is close to working I guess. Anyone know how to program one properly?

Wiring:
[image]

I use BOARD numbering, white wire is ground (20),button 1 (purple wire) connected at (16),button 2 (blck wire) connected at (37),button 3 (gray wire) connected at (31) and button4 (blue wire) connected at (29).

[image]

[image]

Comment: why did you not describe how the keypad is conjected to the RPi? ... also, please include a link to the keypad datasheet ... the link you included tries to redirect to some unknown site ... i will not follow the link

Comment: pictures of the keypad may help ... top and underside

Comment: ooof my bad did not showed how i connected the RPi, was writing this out of frustration. Anyways i bought a keypad similar to this one https://www.adafruit.com/product/1332

Comment: `similar` is kind of useless ... but, follow the tutorials at that link

Comment: start with two wires and connect only one switch ... then same two wires and next switch ... repeat until all four switches are tested ... that will also let you determine which pin is the common ... use same two pins on the RPi throughout this test

Answer (score 1):

You have your GPIO pins configured with (internal) pull-down resistors. Then you are making a circuit where you ground the pin - which is already pulled down - with the keypad switch. Little wonder nothing much happens. Change the pin configs to GPIO.PUD_UP.

p.s. I use the `gpiozero` package quite a bit and prefer it over the older `RPi.GPIO` - there's a lot of built-in functionality in `gpiozero` so you might like to check that out.